# What limits WCF ServiceModelService.Instances?

Tags: wcf, iis, throttling

I'm attempting to load test a WCF service with (IIS6/Server2003/BasicHttpBinding).  The service is throttled as follows:

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100"/>
```

To assess the number of calls on the server I'm using the ServiceModelService 3.0.0.0 performance counters.  If I throttle the maxConcurrentCalls down to 20, 15, 10 or anything lower the Instances performance counter show that WCF is respecting the throttling.  However, if I change maxConcurrentCalls to 30 I'm never able to get Instances to go above 24.  Additionally, Calls Outstanding never goes above 24.  What else could be limiting WCF?

Comment: what binding are you using?  is your service singleton, per session, per call?

Comment: nevermind about the binding, i missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Why Only Two Concurrent Requests for WCF Load Testing?](http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2009/02/08/why-only-two-concurrent-requests-for-load-testing.aspx)

> When I looked at this question, my
>   first response is that: the client did
>   not really send enough requests to the
>   server. Why is that? Here are the
>   reasons:
>
> 1)     If you use the synchronous WCF
>   HttpModule/HttpHandler (installed by
>   default), you would get the maximal
>   number of concurrent requests (held by
>   that number of ASP.NET worker threads)
>   as 12 * [Number of CPU for the
>   Server].
>
> 2)     WCF throttling is
>   specified above.